# function to get a random element of an array bash

Tags: arrays, bash, random

I know how to get a random item from an array like that:

```
declare -a ARRAYISO=(100 200 400 800)
echo ${ARRAYISO["$[RANDOM % ${#ARRAYISO[@]}]"]}
```

I could obviously do that for each array, like a donkey, but I'd like to make a function which takes an array as argument and returns a random element.

I'm trying with:

```
randArrayElement() {
    randElement=${$1["$[RANDOM % ${#$1[@]}]"]} 
    echo  $randElement
}
randArrayElement ARRAYISO
```

but it doesn't like my $1... I've tryed with ", ', ` , bash doesn't interpret the $1 var...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
randArrayElement(){ arr=("${!1}"); echo ${arr["$[RANDOM % ${#arr[@]}]"]}; }
```

and call it as:

```
randArrayElement "ARRAYISO[@]"
```

Comment: Anubhava, this fucntion puts a \n after the value when I call it, how can I remove it? (I use this output in another command which doesn't work because of that), thanks!

Comment: That is due to `echo` command. Use `echo -n ${arr["$[RANDOM % ${#arr[@]}]"]};`

Comment: When I tried the code I get an error `line 11: RANDOM % 0: division by 0 (error token is "0")`. Could you please elaborate more about how to use this function?

Comment: Just make sure you're passing an array to this function